# Questions about contrib/core developement

Tags: discussion

Are questions like "Why is the test of my rules patch postponed?" welcome at Drupal Answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the question is not about an issue found on Drupal.org sites, for which a report should be opened on Drupal.org, the question would be fine, if it is constructive, and not subjective.

We already have a tag about drupal.org questions: [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org).